# How can I make shortcut for "Start SSH session..." under tools in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I frequently use this feature and would like to make a keyboard shortcut for starting a new SSH session. I was not able to find SSH in the keyboard shortcuts options in the settings.

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` then  `All Actions | Plug-ins | SSH Remote Run` ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/ip90UK
where? I don't see an All Actions tab 

Comment: That's how the path was copied by built-in functionality. But you are correct -- there is no `All Actions` tab/node/section there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it faster so:

1. `ctrl + shift + a` search `keymap (settings)`
2. in search bar type `SSH`
3. find under `Main menu -> Tools -> Start SSH session ...` and add your key map

Comment: We can search like that 
Thanks, 
Can we remove the dropdown the "Select Host to Connect" 
in the shortcut too?

Comment: No, you need that if you have more hosts and you need to select one. Why would you want to remove it ?

Comment: What I wanted is a shortcut that starts SSH for a particular host...
So if I have more hosts, I can add more shortcuts

Comment: You can set a key map for the `Start ssh session` and then with the arrows fast select one of the session. Directly doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to @Edwin 's answer, if you want to directly connect to a host

1. ctrl + alt + s (opens settings)
2. Go to Tools > SSH Terminal
3. Select the deployment server you want

So instead of selecting from the SSH Sessions, you can directly connect to your host with your set keymap shortcut